The macro BUILD_BUG_ON_INVALID(e) in linux kernel seems to be no use?
The macro is defined in the kernel like this:
#define BUILD_BUG_ON_INVALID(e) ((void)(sizeof((__force long)(e))))
I test the macro as follows:
#include <stdio.h>

#define BUILD_BUG_ON_INVALID(e) ((void)(sizeof(( long)(e))))
#define true 1

int main() {
    BUILD_BUG_ON_INVALID(true);
    return 0;
}

Then I compile it with:
gcc -Wall -Wextra -c test.c
But I get no warnings (both when true=0 and true=1)
The version of gcc is 11.4.0
I think the point confuses me is what invalid expr is like.

From the kernel header (include/linux/build_bug.h):
/*
 * BUILD_BUG_ON_INVALID() permits the compiler to check the validity of the
 * expression but avoids the generation of any code, even if that expression
 * has side-effects.
 */
#define BUILD_BUG_ON_INVALID(e) ((void)(sizeof((__force long)(e))))

This macro is not meant to check anything at runtime. The only purpose of this macro is to check the validity of the expression passed to it, without actually adding any code.
It is usually used like this (taken from drivers/gpu/drm/i915/i915_memcpy.c):
#if IS_ENABLED(CONFIG_DRM_I915_DEBUG)
#define CI_BUG_ON(expr) BUG_ON(expr)
#else
#define CI_BUG_ON(expr) BUILD_BUG_ON_INVALID(expr)
#endif

In case the config is disabled, we still want the compiler to check that expr is valid, so it will not cause compilation errors when the config is enabled.
In your case, regardless of whether true is 0 or 1, it is a valid expression, so you get no warning. Try putting a bad expression (like a name that doesn't exist) and see what happens

even without the macro, a name that doesn't exist can make a warning(error). i think it's no matters with the macro.

It's true, but say it is instead a function call. Without the macro, if the call is valid, the function will actually be called. The macro keeps the checks but avoids the side effects by using the sizeof

In your example, if the config is enabled, it will check the expr by 'BUG_ON()', otherwise it will do nothing by 'BUILD_BUG_ON_INVALID()'. why not repalce the 'BUILD_BUG_ON_INVALID()' with empty?

Because suppose you always build your kernel without the config, and you added a CI_BUG_ON(expr) with a wrong expression. You will never know it. Then someone else will build with the config enabled and will get the error for your mistake.
